# jquery chat Trying to get user id from a user that i want to send a message

Tags: php, jquery

i have a chat script similar like fb but i have a question, i want to extract user id from an open chat window (like fb) and i don;t know how to do that and to configurate the submit php file to take that id from the user that i want to send the message and insert it to my table. Ex: from id: 1 (me) message toUser id: 2 <-(this toUser id that i want to grab from id 2 window)

I don't have a clue how to do that. Any help appreciated!

This is my db structure:

```
| id | from | toUser | message |
  23   1 (me)   2 <-(this is the user that i want to get)
```

This is the index html:

```
    <a href='#' id='$id'><-(this Id that i want grab)</span> <em>$name $surename</em></a> <-- This is the link from all users name with id's

    <script type="text/javascript">  

    $(document).ready(function() {

         $("#message").keyup(function(evt) {   
         if(evt.which == 13) {
           var toUser = $('#toUser').val();
           $.post("submit.php", { 
            message: $("#message").val(),
            toUser: $("#toUser").val(),},

        function(data){ 

        $("#message").val("");});
    }
     });
    });
</script>
<div class='chat-textarea'>
    <textarea id="message" class="form-control autogrow" placeholder="Type your message"> </textarea>  
        </div>
```

The submit php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message'])){

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'chat';

mysql_select_db($dbname);

$from = $_SESSION['user']; <- This is me

$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';

$toUser = $_POST['toUser']; <- this is not working,return value 0

 if($message != ''){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `messages` VALUES ('','$message','$from','$toUser'";
 mysql_query($sql);
}
 }
?>
```

Comment: dont re-invent chat, use a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your loop for users 
<a href='#' id='toUser' data-message-id="1">
 <a href='#' class='toUser' data-message-id="2">
// loop completes here
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  

    $(document).ready(function() {

         $("#message").keyup(function(evt) {   
         if(evt.which == 13) {
           var toUser = $('.toUser').attr('data-message-id');
           alert(toUser);
           $.post("submit.php", { 
            message: $("#message").val(),
            toUser: toUser,},

        function(data){ 

        $("#message").val("");});
    }
     });
    });
</script>
<div class='chat-textarea'>
    <textarea id="message" class="form-control autogrow" placeholder="Type your message"> </textarea>  
</div>
```

Comment: You need to give class attribute for the users except you

Comment: As same ID cannot be given at multiple places.

Comment: when i manually put  data-message-id="2" it works , if i put  data-message-id="$id" in return's me value 1, i don;t know why it wont read the id 2 of oppened chat user window

Comment: that is because you are giving id="toUser" to every anchor tag, give id="toUser" for your id and give class="toUser" for rest of users.

Comment: i use your two tags but it clones all the users on the page user1 user1-user2-user2. Sorry that i'm being a pain in the ass :)) but i'm new learner, and i thank you for your support and time

Comment: sure i will send'it andi will wait for reply, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

<-(this Id that i want grab) *$name $surename* <-- This is the link from all users name with id's

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#message").keyup(function(evt) {   
     if(evt.which == 13) {
       var toUser = $('#toUser').attr('data-message-id'); // you will get id of the user.
       $.post("submit.php", { 
        message: $("#message").val(),
        toUser: $("#toUser").val(),},

    function(data){ 

    $("#message").val("");});
}
 });
});
```

Comment: did you modify your anchor tag ?

Comment: <a href='#' id='toUser' data-message-id="2">  // like this

Comment: yes, data-message-id="$id" , is ok? but nothing i got value 0 in table

Comment: $("#message").keyup(function(evt) {   
     if(evt.which == 13) {
       var toUser = $('#toUser').attr('data-message-id'); // you will get id of the user.
       $.post("submit.php", { 
        message: $("#message").val(),
        toUser: toUser,},

    function(data){ 

    $("#message").val("");});

Try Using this if you can get the desired value.

Comment: Now is return me value 1, 1 is my id, when i open a window with id 2 and send message to it, it returns me the same value 1

Comment: What do you get in your $id variable ?

Comment: In my $id variable i get id 2

Comment: can you show me your code which is modified as i said you ?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

     $("#message").keyup(function(evt) {   
     if(evt.which == 13) {
       var toUser= $('#toUser').attr('data-message-id');  
       var message = $("#message").val();
       $.post("submit.php", { 
        message: message,
       toUser: toUser,}, 

    function(data){ 
 
    $("#message").val("");});
}
 });
});

Comment: The code is perfect you need to debug as i even tried creating a demo for the same and its working perfect for me.

Comment: This the code with show all the users from users db with chat link and the tag inserted from you, from here it grabs the id:    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";               
    $users = $conn->query($sql);
    foreach ($users as $row) {   
        $name = $row['name'];
        $surename = $row['surename'];
        $status = $row['onlinestatus'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<a href='#' id='toUser' data-message-id='$id'><span class='user-status is-".$status."line'></span> <em>$name $surename</em></a>";